# Im getting a Segmentation fault error and nothing seems to fix it

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I've been getting a segmentation fault error with this code and i really do not know why nor how to solve the issue. Its my first time seeing this kind of error. it only worked when I removed the arguments in the main().

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#define SIZE 100
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int pfd1[2], pfd2[2], spaces = 0, pid;
 char buffer[SIZE];
 if (pipe(pfd1) == -1) {
 perror("pipe failed");
 exit(1); 
 }
 if (pipe(pfd2) == -1) {
 perror("pipe failed");
 exit(1);
 }
 pid = fork();
 if(pid > 0){
 
 close(pfd1[0]);

 write(pfd1[1], argv[1], strlen(argv[1]) + 1); 

 close(pfd1[1]);

 close(pfd2[1]);
 read(pfd2[0], buffer, SIZE);
 close(pfd2[0]);
 printf("Number of spaces is: %s", buffer);
 exit(0);
 }
 else if(pid == 0){

 close(pfd1[1]);
 read(pfd1[0], buffer, SIZE);
 close(pfd1[0]);
 int i=0;
 while (i<=buffer[i]) {
 if(buffer[i]==' ')
 spaces++;
 i++;
 }
 sprintf(buffer,"%d\n",spaces);

 close(pfd2[0]);
 write(pfd2[1], buffer, strlen(buffer) + 1);
 close(pfd2[1]);
 }else{
 perror("fork failed\n");
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi! This is why you need to learn to use a debugger. Maybe try GDB?

Comment: Where does the crash occur?  Where is your diagnostic printing? Where is the indentation? Where is the check that you were passed a command line argument?  How are you running the program?

Comment: As a side note, proper code formatting can go a long way in better helping to understand and follow your code. You might want to better indent your code. Perhaps it was an issue with pasting it?

Answer (score 0):

The parameters **argc** and **argv[]** indicate [command line arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html). As noted in the link, **argc** is the count of arguments (including the executable name) and **argv[]** is an array of null terminated character arrays containing the executable name and the parameters.

For example, if your executable name is *foo* and you execute the program as *foo abc def*, **argc** value will be 3 (3 arguments), the first argument will be *foo* (the executable name) and the remaining arguments will be the rest of the arguments (*abc* and *def*).
In your example, I am assuming you aren't providing any argument other than the program name itself. In this case, the value of **argc** is 1 and only **argv[0]** will exist with the name of the executable. Trying to access **argv[1]** will likely cause a segmentation fault.

I would recommend checking the value of **argc** before accessing any argument values, somewhat like this:

```
if(2 > argc)
{
   printf("Usage is foo abc!");
   exit(1);
}
```